# Using git with certificate in PHPStorm

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

When using `PHPStorm`, I want to integrate `git` in my project, but I can't seem to find the option where you specify the private putty key for the current project..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, had to create a new [private and public key](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-for-git-authorization/) via `git bash`.

Comment: Also visit the GitHub Help - [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).